# Как исправить текст внутри ячеек ведёт себя по разному в IE в отличии от Хрома?

Tags: css3, html, вёрстка, css, html5

http://jsfiddle.net/ASsQh/
Сразу извиняюсь за всё лишнее, копировал прямиком с сайта.

Теперь вот в чём проблема, при так сказать стягивании таблицы в Хроме её содержимое переносится вниз, так называемый перенос строк. 
Вот только хром умный, есть такая ячейка

> солнечная+литиевая батарея

он её разбивает не на 2 строки, а на 3!! То есть для него спецсимволы не помеха.

**В итоге таблицу можно стянуть примерно до 540px!**

В IE же у меня такая проблема, что он этого делать не умеет *(а может и умеет я не знаю на самом деле в чём проблема, это предположение)*
**И в итоге в IE минимальная ширина таблицы примерно 1000px а это уж очень много!!**

Пожалуйста помогите, в чём проблема я не понимаю.

*Откройте jsfiddle в хроме и IE и сами в этом убедитесь*

Comment: а после и перед плюсом поставить пробел нет возможности?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А поставить мягкий перенос (`&shy;`) не помогает? Или `<wbr>`?

Мой Firefox с `<wbr>` переносит: http://jsfiddle.net/ASsQh/3/, без него — нет.

Comment: А ещё с IE можно попробовать [отключить режим совместимости со старыми версиями](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3449338/276994), в нём он ведёт себя лучше.